# Agregar el id en el td como texto

Tags: jquery, html

En ese pedazo de código recorro la tabla el cuerpo y cada td y a cada celda le asigno el color y trate de asignarle el id de cada celda (td) pero lo único que hace es repetirme el ultimo id de la ultima celda.

```
$(function () {
           $("#materiales tbody tr").each(function (index){
               $(this).children("td").each(function (index2){

                   $(".cuadro").css("background-color", "#ECF8E0");
                    $(".cuadro").text( $(this).attr("id") );


               })

           })
       })
```

Alguien que me ayude a solucionarlo

Comment: Cual ID quieres asignarle a cada celda? Tambien, podrìas [edit] tu pregunta y poner tu HTML?

Comment: Bueno lo que quiero hacer es mostrar el id que tiene mi celda cada cuadro de mi tabla tiene un id ejemplo f1-c2 donde f es la fila y  c la columna  `$(".cuadro").text( $(this).attr("id") );`con esto le digo que a cada cuadro escriba el id que tiene para visualizarlo valla como si fueran datos, demas que cada cuadro tiene la clase valga la redundancia `cuadro` per solo me escribe el ultimo id

Comment: Entonces, lo que quieres hacer es que en cada td aparezca en forma de texto visible el ID de ese td?

Comment: aí es pero no entiendo por que no lo hace

Comment: Tambien otra pregunta rapida, ".cuadro" es la clase que tiene cada td? o que es ".cuadro"?

Comment: si, ya que con ella le digo que a los que tengan esa clase escriba su id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que entiendo, estas haciendo mal la referencia al elemento al que quieres poner el `ID`. En esta linea

```
$(this).children("td").each(....
```

Ya estas recorriendo todas las celdas de tu tabla. Según tus comentarios, `.cuadro` es una clase que todas tus celdas tienen, asi que cuando pones

```
 $(".cuadro")...
```

Estas haciendo referencia a todos los elementos que tienen esa clase, por eso pienso que la referencia al elemento es la que esta mal.

Lo que puedes hacer es usar `$(this)` como bien lo estas haciendo hasta ahora. Lo usas de esta forma para hace referencia a la celda en donde estas actualmente:

```
$(this).css("background-color", "#ECF8E0");
$(this).text( $(this).attr("id") );
```

Y así, cada celda ahora mostrará el `ID` que le has puesto.